# iOS JB4ASDK configureSDKWithAppID error code 8: CCSymmetricKeyUnwrap Failure

Tags: ios

On iOS, when trying to configure Salesforce with JB4ASDK configureSDKWithAppID method, I get error code 8: CCSymmetricKeyUnwrap Failure.

With other AppId and AccessToken (from an other app) I have no error.

What may be the cause of that error ? What can I check ?

Thank you.

Comment: Were you able to fix this problem? I have the same one and I can't find any answers on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this answer:

[Getting Error for Update Mobile Push Application in iOS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193305/getting-error-for-update-mobile-push-application-in-ios)

It should address the issue seen here.

Brian Criscuolo, Salesforce Marketing Cloud