# Getting Error for Update Mobile Push Application in iOS

Tags: ios, mobilepush

I'm releasing an iOS App with Mobile Push, and I would like to update my iOS App by changing to a new Mobile Push application.

I created a new Mobile Push application in MarketingCloud, change ApplicationId and AccessToken in the App to the new one, call `configureSDKWithAppID:` to get the following error.

`Error Domain=com.salesforce.jb4asdk Code=8 "CCSymmetricKeyUnwrap Failure
-[ETPush configureSDKWithAppID:andAccessToken:withAnalytics:andLocationServices:andProximityServices:andCloudPages:withPIAnalytics:error:] [Line 884] error = -4304" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=CCSymmetricKeyUnwrap Failure
-[ETPush configureSDKWithAppID:andAccessToken:withAnalytics:andLocationServices:andProximityServices:andCloudPages:withPIAnalytics:error:] [Line 884] error = -4304}`

Reinstalling the App works fine, but since I'd like to update the App, I would like to make it work fine even if I change the ApplicationID.

Is JB4ASDK not allowed to change MobilePush application?

Please advice me if there is a way to avoid errors.

**Environmental**

- JB4ASDK 4.6.0
- Xcode8.3.3
- Swift 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 4.7.0 addressed this use case and handled the different application ID without throwing back an error from our decryption routine. If you upgrade the version of the SDK you are using (we are currently at 4.9.5) we will successfully allow for the changing of the AppID.

Note that in this process, no previously-set data will be maintained (subscriber key, tags, attributes etc.).

http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-iOS/

Brian Criscuolo,
Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Comment: Works fine with 4.9.5 SDK. thanks for explained.